# React native typescript render text onPress

Tags: typescript, react-native, button, onpress

So i am new to React native and typescript. I can't seem to find any way to print something on the page of my app, after a button is pressed.

Here is my function that is called:

```
 const getDuck = () =>{
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*5000 + 1)
        alert(number)
        return <Text>{number}</Text>
        
    }
```

And here is where i am calling it:

```
return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", margin: 8}}>
        <Text>Random number</Text>
        <Button
         title="Press me"
         onPress={() => getDuck()}
         color="#32a852"
        />
        </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the return of an click handler.

Use useState to set the random number.

```
const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = React.useState(0);

 const getDuck = () =>{
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*5000 + 1)
        alert(number)
        setRandomNumber(number);
    }

return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", margin: 8}}>
        <Text>Random number</Text>
        <Button
         title="Press me"
         onPress={() => getDuck()}
         color="#32a852"
        />
        <Text>{randomNumber}</Text>
        </View>
    )
```